# Max angle to prevent object exceeding a max vertical velocity on a frictionless plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

So an object, mass $m$ is on a frictionless plane, making angle $\theta$ to the horizonal. The length of the plane (hypotenuse) is $1m$ and the vertical velocity cannot exceed $2.5 ms^{-1}$ from rest.

[image]

Please take a look at my method and check it's correct

Force down slope $F_{slope} = ma_{slope} = mg \sin(\theta)$

Therefore acceleration down slope $a_{slope} = g \sin(\theta)$

Vertical acceleration $a_{vert} = a_{slope} \sin(\theta) = g \sin^2(\theta)$

Vertical displacement $s_{vert} = \sin(\theta)$

Then we can substitute these into $v_{max}^2 = u_{vert}^2 \times 2a_{vert}s_{vert} $

giving $2.5^2 = 2g \sin^3(\theta)$ and then solve for $\theta$

$$\theta = \arcsin\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{2.5^2}{2g}}\right) = 43^\circ$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's frictionless, there's a much simpler approach. If the height of that wedge is $h$ (which would be $1m\times\sin\theta$ in your case), and your object $m$ starts at the top with $v=0$, then its initial potential energy is $mgh$ and initial kinetic energy $0$. So at the bottom, it's kinetic energy must be $\frac12mv^2=mgh$ and potential energy $0$, no matter how it got from top to bottom (as long as it's frictionless and there are no other losses). And then the vertical component is just $v\sin\theta$.

So if $\ell=1m$ is your hypoteneuse, and $v_{max}=2.5m/sec$ your max vertical speed, then $v=\sqrt{2g\ell\sin\theta}$ and we'd want $\sqrt{2g\ell}\sin^\frac32\theta\leq v_{max}$, or $\sin\theta\leq(\frac{v_{max}}{\sqrt{2gl}})^\frac23$, which is what I believe you wrote (plugging in for $v_{max}$ and $\ell$).